# Author and Title

Tags: fonts, author-number

I dont know how to make an author and title to look exactly like that in screen. Can someone help ?[image]

I used this code but spaces between letters in word "zero" are to small

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\scriptsize Jan Brzechwa}\\{\Huge Z}       {\large E R O}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question has been asked before. Please add a minimal working example of what you have tried. If you do not know where to start you may want to read a beginner's guide.

Comment: I tried this but spaces between letter in "zero" word are to small \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} \usepackage[MeX]{polski} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{indentfirst} \begin{document} \begin{center} {\scriptsize Jan Brzechwa}\\{\Huge Z} {\large E R O} \end{center}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution: with `\textls[600]` I set big letter spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textsf{Jan Brzechwa}\\
\nointerlineskip
{\Huge\scshape\textls[600]{Zero}}
\end{center}

\begin{flushright}\lineskip=5pt
Toczyło się po drodze:\\
,,{\Huge Z drogi}, gdy ja przechodzę!\\
Ja jestem {\Huge sto tisięcy},\\
A może jeszcze {\Huge więcej}''.
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]